# Consulta mysql- agrupar/sumar campos

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gente, les muestro un parte de una tabla para que me entiendan lo que necesito
Esta es mi tabla "detalle_ventas"
Lo que ven marcado en negro son las ventas de un cliente con dni 12345678.
Como veran tengo el campo venta_numero que dice 1 y 6, estos serian los tickets de compra.

la consigna  me pide lo siguiente:

Realizar una consulta que devuelva la cantidad de ventas realizadas al
cliente con dni 12345678. Cantidad de ventas es cada ticket emitido, no cada
producto vendido

El problema es que no se como hacer la consulta porque la que a mi se me ocurre es esta

```
SELECT c.dni,COUNT(dv.venta_numero) as 'Ventas realizadas' FROM detalle_venta dv
INNER JOIN venta v ON v.numero =dv.venta_numero
INNER JOIN clientes c ON c.dni= v.cliente_dni
WHERE c.dni = 12345678;
GROUP BY dv.venta_numero;
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que tengo que cambiar para que me arroje que hay solo DOS VENTAS y no me cuente dos veces el 1 y tres veces el 6???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que la tabla `venta` es el encabezado de cada venta, en primer lugar, no hace falta que involucres a la tabla `detalle_ventas`. Como tampoco vas a ver las ventas de varios clientes, sino de uno en particular, tampoco hace falta agrupar. Simplemente hacer un `count` de los registros que están en la tabla para ese cliente.

Finalmente, como la llave primaria del cliente es el DNI, ya tienes el DNI del cliente en la tabla de ventas y no hace falta tampoco hacer join a la tabla de clientes.

Por ejemplo

```
select count(1) NumeroDeVentas
  from venta v
 where v.cliente_dni = 12345678;
```

Comment: Me ahogue solo en un vaso de agua. Dios mio jajaja. Muchas gracias! Una consulta el COUNT(1) que hace?

Comment: Básicamente, cuenta los registros.  ES más o menos equivalente a hacer `select count(*)` o `select count(cualquiercampo)`. Sobre todo, en la antigüedad, había motores que si hacías `select count(*)` iban y se traían todos los campos de la tabla, solo para contarlos y, en ese entonces, `select count(1)` era un _truco_ para evitar que el motor hiciera algún acceso innecesario al disco. Es de esperar que en tiempos modernos eso ya no ocurra. Son tantos los motores que hay, que ya yo no llevo la cuenta de cual si lo hace o cual no... simplemente sigo utilizando el truco aunque pueda no hacer falta

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

La solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
SELECT
ventas_realizadas.dni, COUNT(ventas_realizadas.venta_numero) AS 'Ventas realizadas'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    c.dni, dv.venta_numero
    FROM
    detalle_venta AS dv
    INNER JOIN 
    venta v 
    ON 
    v.numero =dv.venta_numero
    INNER JOIN 
    clientes c 
    ON c.dni= v.cliente_dni
    WHERE 
    c.dni = 12345678
    GROUP BY 
    dv.venta_numero
) 
AS ventas_realizadas
GROUP BY DNI
```

Mediante un subquery obtienes la cantidad de números de ventas asociados al cliente. Teniendo este resultado preliminar (nombrado temporalmente "ventas realizadas") bastaría contabilizar el numero de registros y agruparlos por el DNI para obtener el total de ventas realizadas a clientes.

### Edit 1

Entendiendo que la relación de la tabla venta y clientes es 1:n, por el contexto del resultado esperado, el query seria el siguiente:

```
SELECT
venta.cliente_dni AS DNI, COUNT(venta.numero) AS 'Ventas realizadas', clientes.*
FROM
venta
LEFT JOIN
clientes
ON
clientes.dni = venta.cliente_dni
WHERE
venta.cliente_dni = 12345678
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,bro. Tambien lo logre utilizando DISTINCT pero estoy seguro que no era esa la idea del ejercicio, porque no la enseñaron hasta el momento y consulta dentro de otra tampoco. Vimos por ahora inner join,left right, y operacion de agregaron. group by ..

Comment: Una duda. El campo *numero* en la tabla *venta* es único? (o sea la relación de *venta* con *detalle_venta* es 1:n). Si ese es el caso, la solución es más simple, y se puede solucionar con un LEFT JOIN de la tabla *venta* con la tabla *clientes*.

Comment: Si, exacto es asi la relacion!